# Joining temp table whilst using row_number()

Tags: sql-server, join, partitioning, row-number

I am trying to get the following table in Microsoft SQL Server. Basically what I am trying to do is to get, for each Sale ID, the sale date (date and time) and the next sale date (date & time), and also the amount of the sale for the first sale date. The table below should explain the later.

[image]

I have done the following coding but haven't managed to get to the table above:

```
DECLARE @date1 AS datetime;
DECLARE @date2 AS datetime;

SET @date1 = DATEADD(HOUR, -72, GETDATE());
SET @date2 = DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE());

SELECT SaleID AS SaleID,
      ,[Sale Date & Time] AS SalesDate
      ,RN
INTO #sales
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SaleID ORDER BY [Sale Date & Time] ASC) AS RN,
             SaleID,
             SalesDate
      FROM Sales
      WHERE [Sale Date & Time] BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2) T;
```

Data from the first part of the query:

[image]

Comment: Where is the value of `amt` coming from? Sample data will help us help you. Also, I really suggest not using object names that must be delimit identified. `[Sale Date & Time]` really isn't a good choice of a name for a column. If you want to have a column with multiple words in it, you're better off using camelCase, PascalCase or Snake_case (like you have with `SalesDate`).

Comment: @Larnu - Amt is coming from `Sales` table it self

Comment: But it's not defined in your subquery, aliased `T`. We can't see your objects, so you need to give a complete example.

Comment: Also, your subquery (`T`) doesn't have a column `[Sale Date & Time]` defined, so the above will error due to an invalid column reference.

Comment: Don't put that in the comments, it makes no sense. [Edit] your question.

Comment: @Larnu added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do the above part just in case someone will find it useful in the future.

below coding was used

```
with cte as

( 

select rownum = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by SalesID order by [Sales Date & Time] asc)
,SalesID,[Sale Date & Time],[Amount]
from Sales
where [Sales Date & Time] between GETDATE()-7 and GETDATE()
)

select 

    a.SalesID
    ,a.[Sale Date & Time] 
    ,b.Sale Date & Time] 
    ,a.[Amount]

from cte a

inner join cte b on b.rownum = a.rownum+1 and a.SalesID=b.SalesID
```